# Shortest path algorithm js error

Tags: javascript, json, algorithm, shortest-path, bellman-ford

I am quite new into JS and a friend of mine sent me this fiddle

```
function shortestPath(g, s) {
    g.vertexes.forEach(function(u) {
        u.dist = Infinity;
        u.prev = null;
    });

    s.dist = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < g.vertexes.length - 1; i++) {
        g.edges.forEach(function(e) {
            update(e);
        });
    }

    printResult(); }

function update(e) {
    var u = e.from;
    var v = e.to;

    if (v.dist > u.dist + e.data) {
        v.dist = u.dist + e.data;
        v.prev = u;
    } }

var result = [];

function printResult() {
    var str = '';
    debugger;
    for (var i = 0; i < result[0].length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < result.length; j++) {
            str += result[i][j] + ' ';
        }
        console.log(str);
        str = '';
    } }

function printGraph(G) {
    var a = [];

    G.vertexes.forEach(function(u) {
        a.push(u.dist);
    });
    result.push(a); }


function Graph(options) {
    options = options || {};
    this.directed = (options.directed != null) ? options.directed : true;
    this.vertexes = [];
    this.edges = []; }

Graph.prototype.vertex = function(name) {
    var v = {
        adjacent: [],
        name: name.toString()
    };

    this.vertexes.push(v);

    return this; };

Graph.prototype.get = function(name) {
    return this.vertexes.filter(function(el) {
        return el.name === name.toString();
    })[0]; };

Graph.prototype.edge = function(a, b, w) {
    var that = this;

    connect(a, b, w);
    if (!this.directed) {
        connect(b, a, w);
    }

    function connect(a, b, data) {
        var u = that.vertexes.filter(function(el) {
            return el.name === a.toString();
        })[0];
        var v = that.vertexes.filter(function(el) {
            return el.name === b.toString();
        })[0];

        u.adjacent.push(v);
        that.edges.push({
            from: u,
            to: v,
            data: data
        });
    }

    return this; };



function main() {
    var g = new Graph();
    g.vertex(1)
        .vertex(2)
        .vertex(3)
        .vertex(4)
        .vertex(5)
        .vertex(6)
        .vertex(7)
        .vertex(8);

    g.edge(1, 2, -2);
    g.edge(1, 5, -2);
    g.edge(1, 6, -3);
    g.edge(1, 8, -1);

    g.edge(2, 6, 7);
    g.edge(2, 8, 4);
    g.edge(3, 2, 2);
    g.edge(3, 4, 5);

    g.edge(3, 7, 9);
    g.edge(4, 7, 4);
    g.edge(5, 7, 5);
    g.edge(7, 8, -1);

    g.edge(8, 2, 2);
    g.edge(8, 5, 8);
    g.edge(8, 6, 3);
    g.edge(8, 7, 7);

    shortestPath(g, g.get(3));
    console.log(g); }

main();
```

(Shortest path Bellman-Ford)
and don't really get it why it throws the error `property 'length' of undefined` in the console.

Any advice how to fix this error?

Comment: I have downvoted your question, because you have not included full code needed to reproduce the problem. Please do not rely on external sites (like JSFiddle) as the _sole_ location for code; if those sites go down, your question becomes rather useless. If you edit your question to include all the code necessary to reproduce your problem, I will gladly remove the downvote.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, didn't know about this, noob to Stackoverflow too.

Comment: I formatted your code, but apparently you edited the question at the same time, and my edits were discarded; anyway, have a look at this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks/22189#22189

Comment: m69, noticed - thanks

Comment: To make sure a user is notified of a comment you write, include their name in your comment preceded by `@`, like `@m69`. In fact, when you type an `@` and an additional character at the start of a comment, you'll get a pop-up menu with the names of the users in the previous comments whose username starts with that letter. Click this menu to avoid typos and trouble with spaces and other special characters. (The author of the question or answer above the comments is always notified.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, when JS complains `Cannot read property "xxx" of undefined`, that means that somewhere you have `foo.xxx` and `foo` is the JavaScript value `undefined` (which is not an object, and has no properties).

Track such a problem down by finding the line in question (using debugging tools, or even just looking for `.length` in your case) and considering: when might the variable in question be `undefined`?

In your specific case, the error occurs on this line:

```
for (var i = 0; i < result[0].length; i++) {
```

which means that `result[0]` is `undefined`. Which means that your `result` array has no value at `[0]`. It is empty.

Since the `printResult` function is called from one place (line 59), this likely means that `result` is still an empty array when `printResult()` is called. You can confirm this by setting a breakpoint at that location and examining what `result` is.

As for why it is empty:

The only code that affects the `result` array is `result.push(a)` in the `printGraph()` function. And this function is never called. Ask your friend why s/he defined `printGraph()` but never invoked it.

It may be as simple as calling `printGraph(g)` right before `printResult()`.

Comment: it works now, thank you for explaining step by step!

Comment: You're welcome. Please note that if this answer has fully solved your problem, it would be appreciated if you would mark this answer is "accepted" by clicking the checkmark.